# Malloc and free multiple pointers

Tags: c++, malloc

I'm working with a c++ program that uses multiple buffers and I'm getting a seg fault a few minutes into running the program.  I'm unsure of the correct way to go about it.  The code that I think is giving me the fault is currently as such:

```
int *myBuf1, *myBuf2;
myBuf1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxPacketSize);
myBuf2 = myBuf1;
// do work

if(myBuf1) {
    free(myBuf1);
}
myBuf1 = NULL;
myBuf2 = NULL;
```

My first question is:  with the assignment 'myBuf2 = myBuf1', does myBuf2 allocate a different block of memory with sizeof(int) * maxPacketSize, or is it just a pointer to the same block of memory allocated by myBuf1?

Secondly, should I be freeing myBuf2 as well as myBuf1, then setting both to NULL?  Above I'm only freeing myBuf1.  OR, is it best to do:

```
myBuf1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxPacketSize);
myBuf2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxPacketSize);
```

then free both?

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` and `free` in C++? Why don't you know where the segfault is coming from? Run the application with gdb. Use `bt` to find the function that is causing the crash. Watch variables. The check before `free` is useless. Otherwise, the problem must be in `do work`. The code you show will not sefault.

Comment: Please turn on the warnings on your compiler. Things get a lot easier when the compiler tells you what is wrong before you even know something is wrong.

Comment: Well the project was originally written in C, and it has been 'ported' I guess you could say, to C++.  The code in the '// do work' section calls various other funtions that require a buffer to be passed in.  Also, I've loaded the core file in gdb, and the segfault is coming from a 'linked_list.h', which isn't even in my project, I assume it's from some library.

Comment: Also, how is the check before 'free' useless?  If you try to free a null pointer, wouldn't that result in a seg fault?

Comment: freeing a NULL pointer is OK with free(). Nothing is freed, that's all. It's not an error and, in fact, C99 demands that it not be an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Q: with the assignment 'myBuf2 = myBuf1', does myBuf2 allocate a
>   different block of memory?

A: No

> Q: Secondly, should I be freeing myBuf2 as well as myBuf1?

A: No.  One malloc (), one free().

```
Q: [Should I] then set both to NULL?
```

A: Yes, I would strongly encourage setting ALL pointers to NULL.

Comment: It's actually worse ... `myBuf2` is an `int` *not* a pointer. There is no guarantee that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)` (In fact, on any 64 bit system you're almost guaranteed it's not) - the compiler should be complaining about this from the git go.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is a typo.. it's supposed to be int * for both.

Answer (score 2):

First, you haven't declared two pointers.

```
int *myBuf1, myBuf2;
```

This declares a `myBuf1` as an `int*` and `myBuf2` as an `int` (not a pointer). You need to write:

```
int *myBuf1, *mBuf2;
```

Second, no, assigning one pointer to another does not copy the memory, it just creates two pointers that point to the same thing.

You only need to `free` one. Also, there is no need to set to `NULL` afterwards, although in some cases it can help in avoiding some tricky bugs.

Comment: What he needs is to put each variable on its own line ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `myBuf1` to `myBuf2` simply makes `myBuf2` point to the same location as `myBuf1`. Consequently doing this:

```
myBuf1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxPacketSize);
myBuf2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxPacketSize);
```

and then `myBuf1 = myBuf2;` will just allocate memory for `myBuf2` for no reason.

Conclusion: freeing any one of them will be sufficient.

And BTW your `myBuf2` is just an `int`, not an `int*`, which is probably the cause for your segfault.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo, it is supposed to be int*

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int *myBuf1, myBuf2;
```

to

```
int *myBuf1, *myBuf2;
```

If you want to have to distinct blocks of memory, you will need two separate allocations:

```
myBuf1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxPacketSize);
myBuf2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxPacketSize);
```

Consider using `calloc`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will read up on calloc.  Also it was a typo, supposed to be *myBuf2

Answer (score 0):

After the line:

```
myBuf1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxPacketSize);
```

you ***must*** check that malloc( ) did not return a NULL pointer, indicating failure. e.g:

```
myBuf1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxPacketSize);
if (myBuf1 == NULL) {
  printf ("malloc ( ) failed!\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: [Should I] then setting both to NULL?
>
> A: Yes, I would strongly encourage setting ALL pointers to NULL.

If you are inside a block, there no use of setting back pointers to null. For the compiler, it's doing nothing and for the reader it's more confusing.

In C++, it's a good practice to use blocks to limit the scope of identifiers, especially pointers.